# Ckeditor upload image functionality disappeared? - Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have installed ckeditor and for a while it had image upload functionality but now it seem absent.

Is there something that i do not know?

I am using carrierwave + minimagick, i also have rmagick installed for another part of the site. i do not think that these two correlate?

config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.height = 800;
}
```

intializer

```
Ckeditor.setup do |config|

  require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"

end
```

Comment: paste your app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js and config/initializers/ckeditor.rb

Comment: @matanco edited my post thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your initializer:

```
config.assets_plugins = ['image']
```

and to your JS file:

```
config.toolbar_Pure = [
    '/',{
      name: 'insert',
      items: ['Image']
    }
  ];
```

you can see full configuration here:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  config.language = 'en';
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.toolbar_Pure = [
    '/', {
      name: 'basicstyles',
      items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
    }, {
      name: 'paragraph',
      items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']
    }, {
      name: 'links',
      items: ['Link', 'Unlink']
    }, '/', {
      name: 'styles',
      items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']
    }, {
      name: 'colors',
      items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor']
    }, {
      name: 'insert',
      items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'PageBreak']
    }
  ];
  config.toolbar = 'Pure';
  return true;
};
```